# Prevent next state in angular-ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

How can I do that with ui-router? In ng-route I'm using this syntax :

router

```
.when('/login',{
    templateUrl:'app/view/page/users/login.html',
    isLogged:true
})
```

app run

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart',function(event,next) {
    if(next.$$route.isLogged){
        console.log('...')
    }
})
```

But It not work with ui-router.
I tried change to

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',function(event,next) {
    if(next.$$state.isLogged){
        console.log('...')
    }
})
```

And I get `islogged underfine` . How can I do that with angular-ui-router

**EDIT**

Here is state I want prevent . When user login , I push token of user in localStorage . And I want when user login , cant go state register. 
Here is router

```
.state('register',{
                        url:'/register',
                        templateUrl:'app/view/page/users/register.html',
                        controller:'regCtrl',
                        controllerAs:'vm',
                        isLogged:false

                    })
```

Here is code I push in local storage

```
function authLogin(logData) {
                    return 

    $http.post('/api/authenticate',logData).then(function(data) {
                            if(data.data.token){
                                console.log(data);
                            authToken.setToken(data.data.token);
                            return data.data;
                        }

                        });
                    };
```

Comment: please post details of states you defined using ui-router.

Comment: @Pengyy I edited my question . Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution for ui-router(lower than 1.0.0):**

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',function(event,next) {
    if(next.isLogged){         //  <------access property directly here
        // console.log('...')
        event.preventDefault();
        return $state.go('any other state');
    }
})
```

**Solution for ui-router(1.0.0+):**

stateChange event has been deprecated in ui-router 1.0.0+ and for the new version, you should use `$transitions` (*have to inject first*)

```
$transitions.onStart({}, function(transition) {
    if(!transition.to().isLogged) {         // <------ access toState properties by transition.to()
        return false;  
    }
});
```

Comment: @georgeawg ok, thanks for your attention. I've edit the answer to be more readable to others. Let me know if there are other things I should do. Thanks again. :)

Comment: [Great Answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/25/great-answer) are ones that are useful to other readers.

Comment: awesome . Thank you